# Compare two data frames items in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames which both have one column:

df1

```
Server
A
B
c
d
```

df2

```
Server
a
f
z
x
```

I need to check if df1$Server exists in df2$Server. If yes, I need to add a column in df1 and put 1 else put 0.

I have this code, I think the algorithm is right but it does not seem to be working.  Any input is appreciated.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
    if (df1[i,1] %in% row.names(df2)) {
        df1[i,2]<-c(1)
    } else{
        df1[i,2]<-(0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are `a`, `f`, `z`, and `x` the row names of `df2`? Should the comparison be case-sensitive?

Comment: You may want to read up a bit on the difference between row names and row elements, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler than you're making it:

```
df1$LogicalColumn <- as.numeric(df1$Server==df2$Server)
```

This will sequence along each column and check for pairwise equality.

```
df1$LogicalColumn <- as.numeric(df1$Server %in% df2$Server)
```

This will check all values of `df2`'s column for each value of `df1$Server`. If it really is the rownames you're concerned with (why?), replace `df2$Server` with `rownames(df2)` in either context.

Comment: if one were to compare numbers,  `==` will fail in the general case for floats.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The solution being to do something like this? `mapply(function(x,y) isTRUE(all.equal(x,y)),df1$Server,df2$Server)`

Comment: @Senor o, that was great and very fast rather than doing the loops. Thanks you so much.

Comment: @BlueMagister  Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 0):

The default row names will be numbers, unless you have assigned them:

```
  Server
1      a
2      b
3      c
4      d
5      e

> row.names(df3)
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
```

What you want is to compare against the values, not the names of the rows:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
  if (df1[i,1] %in% df2$Server) {
    df1[i,2]<-c(1)
  } else{  
    df1[i,2]<-(0)
  }            
}
```